# Migrate database between free and paid app

Tags: c#, database, windows-phone-7

The problem scenario is as follows:

There is a free wp7 app with a local database, the database file is in isolated storage.

When the user decides to get the paid version of that app, then this is like having a new app (**is this correct?**). Because it is a new app, the data in the database of the free app will not be available in the just paid app.

Is there a way to migrate the database content between the free and the paid app?

EDIT: I know that I could upload the data from the free app to a webservice, and then download it into the paid app. As this might be a solution I don't want to do that, because I don't want to maintain the webserver. I'm looking for a solution that works on the phone without online interaction.

Comment: you can upload the encrypted DB (with a user-entered key) from the free app as a backup and migration path and then download it from the paid app, let the user enter a key and decrypt it...

Comment: If its the same app, then you could just do a trial. The IsolatedStorage from Trial -> Paid remains.

Comment: This is why you should used the Trial API, instead of spammed the marketplace with two apps.

Comment: thanks claus and willmel for that hint, I wasn't aware of that API

Answer (score 0):

Not a fan of this solution, but as a last resort, you could open up a migration point in the **public** file system, drop the data there using the old app and then import into the new app.

Comment: sorry, I dont understand, what is a migration point? I thought wp7 apps are sandboxed, so you can not access data outside isolated storage (media in the media library being the exception). can you give me a link or some further information on how to access files outside isolated storage? thanks!